# Access java web service in Android

Tags: java, android, ksoap2

I have a problem while calling a Java web service from an Android application using ksoap2.  My web service class has a private variable, and I used getters & setters to update that variable. I want to get the value to the Android application through using the get method. How can I do that?  Please help me! I'm new to programming.

My web service class:

```
public class Customer {
    private String customerName;

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }
```

I used a demo class to set the customer name value. but when running the app using an emulator, it doesn't give the value which should be. It shows only the opening default message

```
package com.testversiontwo.ws;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TestVTwoClientActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.customer.com";
    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "getCustomerName";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.customer.com/getCustomerName/";
    private static final String URL = "http://175.157.141.120:8085/TestVTwo/services/Customer?wsdl";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);          

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new     SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            Log.i("myApp", response.toString());

            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("Message :"+response);
            setContentView(tv);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please mention your request and response format also.Because some request and response formats are not supported by ksoap.

Comment: Before we can help you should have a look at the FAQ. You must provide more context. It is absolutely unclear what your problem is. Please post some code (relevant parts) and/or some exception stack traces.

Comment: blah blah blah - what have you done, post your code - blah blah blah

Comment: What exactly does not work? Any exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your URL must be:

```
private static final String URL = "http://175.157.141.120:8085/TestVTwo/services/Customer";
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've realised that `getCustomerName` returns a String, so you have to do:

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("Message :" + response.toString());
setContentView(tv);
```

If there are still errors, post the exception stack trace.

Comment: No this does not give any exception. But the android application doesn't show the value set by the demo java class. It shows only Hello world the default message. I tried to convert the response value into a string but this also doesn't solve the problem.....
I think the problem in set method it does't update variable correctly. When I use the private variable like this "private String name = "Sean";" the android client shows the correct value. I want to know how to update the private value in the server correctly. 
Thanx all of you for spending your time on my question.

Answer (score 0):

OK!! I have solved that problem by using a MySQL database & creating an Android client to access that MySQL database!!!